# Where to find a replacement bolt for this vintage bike?

Tags: parts, vintage

My vintage bike has some problems. The bolt in the photo (click to enlarge) is on the verge of death.
I need to buy a new one, it is about 42mm long.
I have no idea where to buy it. Are there compatible products?
The frame is Giacomelli.

Thank you.
PS. What is the exact name of that?

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: There's FB group named the "League of Ordinary Riders" who have many vintage bicycle fanatics some of which should be able to help with any repair or parts fabrication issues. One guy in particular I know on this group in the UK who specializes in this space is Ed Knight. He's even fabricated extinct bicycles from museum drawings. I'm sure if you or anybody else is struggling to keep a vintage bicycle in repair, Ed or one of the other group members should be able to help you or point you in the right direction.

Comment: FWIW, I wouldn't refer to the parts on that bike as "vintage".

Comment: Since you can use basically any old bolt for that: Are you asking where to obtain something that fits the vintage character in look and feel? Ideally, the same part?

Answer (score 8):

The part you are looking at is a seatpost binder bolt. These are easily available at a variety of price levels and different materials, generally chrome-plated cromoly are the best but the stainless steel ones are quite nice.

There are a couple of different types; the most common are the type that have a little nub that fits into a slot/cut in the hole for the binder bolt, but not all frames have this. Another type has a serration to fit a frame with round holes only. To me it looks like your frame can use the first type.

Sizing is generally standard but sometimes these are made overlength and need cutting down to size. In a pinch, you can use a suitable length recessed brake nut and an M6 bot with washer to get a good clamping action.

These bolts used to be manufactured by big names like Campagnolo etc etc but the only branded new ones I've seen recently are Tange. They are generally nowadays otherwise unmarked by branding.

When you know the proper name of the part, it is easy to search your favourite bike parts supplier, marketplace or speak to a bike shop over the phone.